# Geometric distributions and memorylessness

Tags: probability

I need an advice or a solution on how to solve the following:

We say that the discret random variable $T$ is memoryless, if

$\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{P}\{ T > m+n \, | \, T > m \} = \mathbb{P}\{ T > n\}$

1. Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}^{\ast}$. Show that if $X$ follows a geometric distribution of parameter $p \in ]0,1]$, then is memoryless.
2. Let $X$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{N}^{\ast}$, that is memoryless. Show that $X$ follows a geometric distribution and specify the parameter $p$.

EDIT:

So far I found for the first one the following:

$P \{ T > n \} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\{T = i\} = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n (1-p)^{i-1}p = 1 - p\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-p)^{i-1} = 1 - p\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)} = (1-p)^n$

Then I got:

$\mathbb{P}\{T>m+n \, | \, T>m\} = \frac{\mathbb{P} \{T>m+n \,\, and \,\, T>m\} }{\mathbb{P} \{T > m\}} = \frac{\mathbb{P} \{T>m+n\} }{\mathbb{P} \{T > m\}} = \frac{(1-p)^{n+m}}{(1-p)^m} = (1-p)^n = \mathbb{P}\{T>n\}$

So the first point is good.

EDIT2:

For the second point I found so far:

$P(X=n) = P(X>n-1) - P(X>n) = P(X>n \,|\, X>1) - P(X>n)= \frac{P(X>n \, and \,  X>1)}{P(X>1)} - P(X>n) = \frac{P(X>n)}{P(X>1)} - P(X>n) = \frac{1 - P(X>1)}{P(X>1)} \cdot P(X>n) = \frac{P(X=1)}{P(X>1)} \cdot P(X>n)$.

Then I'm lost.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For the first one I found:

$P \{ T > n \} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\{T = i\} = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n (1-p)^{i-1}p = 1 - p\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-p)^{i-1} = 1 - p\frac{1-p^n}{1-p} = \frac{1-p-p(1-p)^n}{1-p}$

Then I tried to calculate $\mathbb{P}\{T>m+n \, | \, T>m\} = \frac{\mathbb{P} \{T>m+n \, and \, T > m\} }{\mathbb{P} \{T > m\}} = = \frac{\mathbb{P} \{T>m+n\} }{\mathbb{P} \{T > m\}}$.

But that doesn't help me further.

Comment: @J.C. You made a mistake for summing geometric series. The common ratio is $1-p$, not $p$. Also $p(1-p^n)\neq p(1-p)^n$

Comment: I see, didn't even notice. So the sum actually gives me $\mathbb{P}\{T > n \} = (1-p)^n$, which is then much easier for $\frac{\mathbb{P}\{ T > m+n \}}{\mathbb{P}\{T > m\}}$, which actually gives me $(1-p)^n$ again, which is $\mathbb{P}\{T>n\}$. Thank you a lot. Any hint for the second one?

Comment: @J.C. For the second part, I think this is relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392000/prove-that-any-positive-integer-valued-random-variable-with-memoryless-property

Comment: I still don't know how to use the link you gave me, because it uses a slightly different definition of memorylessness and it nees solving a functional equation, which I don't understand.  I tried again and found what I put on the top under 'Edit2'.

Answer (score 0):

1) Suppose $X\sim Geom(p)$. Then $P(T>m+n|T>m)=\dfrac{P(>m+n,T>m)}{P(T>m)}=\dfrac{P(T>m+n)}{P(T>m)}=\dfrac{P(T=m+n+1)+P(T=m+n+2)+...}{P(T=m+1)+P(T=m+2)+...}$ wich is easly to calculate.

2) $P(X>n)=P(X>m+n|X>m)=\dfrac{P(X>m+n,X>m)}{P(X>m)}=\dfrac{P(X>m+n)}{P(X>m)}$. Thus $P(X>n)P(X>m)=P(X>m+n)$. That is, $(1-F_X(m))(1-F_X(n))=(1-F_X(m+n))$, and therefore $F_X(m)+F_X(n)=F_X(m+n)+F_X(m)F_X(n)$.

But the general solution of the last functional equation is $F_X(n)=1-c^n$ for some constant $c$. Can you continue?

Comment: I don't understand how you proceed from line $P(X>n)P(X>m) = P(X>m+n)$ to the next and what $F_X$ is. I'm new to this subject, btw.

Comment: $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$. Mmm it is interesting that you talk about an excercise related to distributions and don't know the usual notation.

Comment: Ok, now I see. We met this notation in measure theory course, but not in probability course (I know those two courses are strongly related). But I still don't know how to jump from one line to the other.

Comment: If F_X=P(X\le x), what is 1-F_X(x)?

Comment: $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) \Rightarrow 1-F_X(x) = P(X > x)$. Oh right, of course. What is this general solution $F_X(n) = 1-c^n$ you wrote about?