# How I can prove that in the discrete case only the geometric distribution has the memorylessness property?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How I can prove that in the discrete case **only** the geometric distribution has the *memorylessness* property? $$\mathbb P(\xi > a + b) = \mathbb P(\xi > a) \mathbb P(\xi > b)$$

In old questions I could not find an answer to this question

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392000/prove-that-any-positive-integer-valued-random-variable-with-memoryless-property?rq=1

Comment: You already asked this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3859563/321264.